# Generate XMP sidecars automatically on Digikam

Tags: xmp, digikam

I'm using Digikam 5.3.0 on Debian and I'm importing some pictures either from an external SD card or downloading from Google Drive. The pictures that I've imported from the Importing assistant seems to have generated the XMP files automatically, but the ones that I've copied by hand on the Digikam folder have not generated. What is the correct process? I've selected the options

- Read from secondary Files
- Write to secondary Files 
  Write only to XMP files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import the hand copied files into digiKam, then it should write hte XMP files.